# Gnome Terminal error with VT100 cursor movement codes

Tags: linux-mint, vim, gnome-terminal

I've got an ansi escape issue with Gnome Terminal. What could be causing and how do I fix an issue like this? Since I cannot describe the issue very well I have a screenshot to show it off. When I edit a line in the terminal or change lines in Vim I get what looks like a partial ansi escape sequence. In the image below it is the blue highlighted areas. These should not be there, and instead should be the correctly colored text.

[image]

Comment: I found about about the program `vttest`. It shows that my cursor movement codes are not working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

That could be a plugin attempting to change the text-cursor appearance.  tmux uses the feature as well, e.g, as in the [`xterm+tmux`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/terminfo-contents.html#tic-xterm_tmux) building block for terminal descriptions.  The application is sending a `DECSCUSR` control sequence, described in [XTerm Control Sequences](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-Ps-SP-q.1D81):

```
CSI Ps SP q
          Set cursor style (DECSCUSR, VT520).
            Ps = 0  -> blinking block.
            Ps = 1  -> blinking block (default).
            Ps = 2  -> steady block.
            Ps = 3  -> blinking underline.
            Ps = 4  -> steady underline.
            Ps = 5  -> blinking bar (xterm).
            Ps = 6  -> steady bar (xterm).
```

and the `6` on your screenshot likely refers to the `6` listed here.  That was added in [patch #282](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_282) (2012/09/28), and is as noted an ***xterm*** feature.

Referring to the source code for tmux 2.1, it has a compiled-in default value for the `terminal-override` setting:

```
    { .name = "terminal-overrides",
      .type = OPTIONS_TABLE_STRING,     
      .default_str = "xterm*:XT:Ms=\\E]52;%p1%s;%p2%s\\007"
                     ":Cs=\\E]12;%p1%s\\007:Cr=\\E]112\\007"
                     ":Ss=\\E[%p1%d q:Se=\\E[2 q,screen*:XT"
    },
```

Comment:

- The `XT` should be redundant (since ncurses' database would have that).  It is defined more or less in the `screen` manual page.
- The `Ms` string relates to selection-data (you might want that, but then again the odds of it being supported correctly in other terminals is minimal)
- The others are for cursor appearance.

As a quick check, you could set `terminal-overrides` in your `tmux.conf`, omitting the cursor features:

```
terminal-overrides xterm*:XT:,screen*:XT
```

Comment: I do see the failure in tmux. Especially when scrolling through the history.

Comment: Note: gnome-terminal 3.16 (actually its underlying vte 0.40) added support for these escape sequences.